# Need to deploy the Azure Policy for the Tags only for the VM

Tags: azure, tags, resources, azure-policy

I am deploying the Azure policy for the Recommended Tags that need to be applied when anyone creates the new VM.
I found one in-built policy: Require a tag on resources

But when I deployed, it will be applied to all the resources and I need a policy for only VM resources.

Also how I can use more than one tag in a single policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your policy rule, you must indicate that the policy is just for VMs

For example:

```
...
"policyRule": {
          "if": {
            "field": "type",
            "in": [
              "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
              "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            ...
          }
    }
...
```

Hope this helps!